# trouble publishing app on IIS, always landing on welcome page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, networking

I'm trying to publish a C# app on my windows PC but cant succeed using IIS,

I've been publishing my app with with visual studio no problem,
When i add a new website on IIS and only specify the name and physical path the app is indeed working on localhost,
But when i add my IP to the host name, i can connect, but always land on IIS Welcome Page...

I've tried to move my published folder inside the default website folder but it does'nt seem to work either.

default page for reference
[image]

Comment: For all sites on IIS, review their site bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background and you will see why the requests land on the default site, not yours.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion from Lex Li. You could try to check the bindings for all the sites in the IIS. Make sure other sites does not using that IP address in the binding. You need to add the IP to the IP address field and keep the host name empty. Try to restart the site and see if it works if enter IP address in the browser.